# Python & qtDesigner uic pop-up window lineEdit access

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, uic

I'm newbie.
I want to click a pushButton to open a new window and take text from main window lineEdit and copy to new pop-up window lineEdit.

So far I an create new window but can't access lineEdit. No errors, app is not responding.

This is what I have:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic

app = QApplication([]) #Main Window
ui = uic.loadUi(r"D:\UI_test\gui\main_gui_TT.ui")

appedit = QApplication([]) #Pop-up
uiedit = uic.loadUi(r"D:\UI_test\gui\input_TT.ui")

def edit1():
    uiedit.show()
    appedit.exec_()
    uiedit.lineEdit_CC.setText('text') <-this line is a problem


ui.pushButton_1edit.pressed.connect(edit1)
ui.show()
app.exec_()
```

Please help what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only have a single QApplication even if you have many windows, considering the above the solution is:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic

app = QApplication([])  # Main Window
ui = uic.loadUi(r"D:\UI_test\gui\main_gui_TT.ui")

uiedit = uic.loadUi(r"D:\UI_test\gui\input_TT.ui")


def edit1():
    uiedit.show()
    uiedit.lineEdit_CC.setText("text")


ui.pushButton_1edit.pressed.connect(edit1)
ui.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Hello, I have made the proposed adjustment but still the same problem. There must be something else I mixed up.

Comment: Ok, it works! Thanks a lot. My qt designer required save. Thanks!!